# Can you specify a default value for a function or sub parameter of type Func or Action?

Tags: .net, vb.net, default-value, func

Consider the following code (don't mind the design, it's just an example):

```
Private _value As Boolean

Public Sub SetValue(Optional getValue As Func(Of Boolean) = ... )
    _value = getValue()
End Sub
```

How can I get this to work without using `Nothing` ?
For the sake of simplicity let's say I want the default value to be a function that always returns `True`. Can it be done? If so, can it be done inline?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default values for optional parameters must be constant expressions ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/optional-parameters)).

In .NET, you can only have constants of “primitive types” (Boolean, Byte, Char, DateTime, Decimal, Double, Integer, Long, Short, Single, or String, [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/constants-enums/how-to-declare-a-constant)).

So you cannot use a function reference as a default value.

As a workaround, you can use:

```vb
Private _value As Boolean

Public Sub SetValue(Optional getValue As Func(Of Boolean) = Nothing )
    _value = If(getValue(), DefaultFunc())
End Sub
```

Or you could use an overload:

```vb
Private _value As Boolean

Public Sub SetValue(getValue As Func(Of Boolean))
    _value = getValue()
End Sub

Public Sub SetValue()
    _value = GetDefaultValue()
End Sub
```

Comment: Very clear answer, thanks ! :D